# Reading messages from IBM MQ asynchronously - download many messages

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

Below is the code responsible for creating the connection:

```
IConnection connectionMQ;

factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
IConnectionFactory cf = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();

cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "host");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, port);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "channel");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "queueManager"); 
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_PEER_NAME, "sslPeerName"); 
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SPEC, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"); 
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CCSID, "ccSid");
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, "*USER");
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CLIENT_CERT_LABEL, "clientCertLabel");

connectionMQ = cf.CreateConnection();
```

Consumer :

```
using (sessionWMQ = connectionWMQ.CreateSession(true, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge))
{

    var destination = sessionWMQ.CreateQueue("queueName");
    consumerAsync = sessionWMQ.CreateConsumer(destination);
    var messageListener = new MessageListener(OnMessageCallback);
    consumerAsync.MessageListener = messageListener;

    connectionWMQ.Start();
}
```

OnMessageCallback:

```
public void OnMessageCallback(IMessage message)
{
    if (message != null)
    {
        numMessage++;
        sessionWMQ.Commit();
    }
}
```

This implementation causes me to download exactly one message and not the next ones.
What should I change to download all messages and even if the queue is empty it will wait for the message?

I will add that there is no error and this message is correctly taken from the queue and the next time I connect this message is gone.

Comment: I'm guessing that because you wrap the sessionWMQ in a using, that as soon as you call `.Start().`  you immediately dispose the session.  I would try keeping the session open until you quit the program, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: What version of MQ is your dll from?  Please provide the full version.

Comment: @Neil Unfortunately, it didn't help or I don't know how to maintain the session. I changed to sessionWMQ = connectionWMQ.CreateSession(true, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge)

Comment: @JoshMc IBMXMSDotnetClient 9.3.0.1

Comment: Try adding Console.ReadLine() after connectionWMQ.Start(). This will make the thread to wait for key to be pressed. This is just for testing, not ideal for production.

Comment: @Shashi Now it downloaded all the messages and didn't close the connection after download, which is what I expect

Comment: @Shashi There is a nicer solution, I can't use wait for key in production?

Comment: What happens after the start() routine?  Does it just exit the Using loop?  If so will it close all of the variables in the loop.
Knowing nothing about C## my guess is that the start() initiates another threads which processes one message, then the start() ends, and the loop is closed.